# What is the dress code for the Vienna State Opera (Standing Room Section)?

Tags: vienna, dress-codes

I want to see an Opera when I visit Vienna. Since the all the cheap seats have already been sold, I plan to pay €3 for a standing room ticket. I'm guessing the standing crowd will not be as well-dressed as the €190 seats. How nice should I dress? Do I need a tie? I was thinking nice slacks and a long-sleeve collared shirt.

Comment: [This link](https://www.concertvienna.com/blog/vienna-opera/how-to-attend-the-opera/) was rather easy to find and tells you all you need to know.

Comment: Thanks. That not only explained how people dressed but gave a great overview of the experience.

Comment: Do you have any experience with the standing stalls at the state opera? If not, I would suggest you do some research upfront (or ask a question here, if you don't find anything), as there are quite a few things to pay attention to.

Comment: The link in Weather Vane's comment gave a good description of the experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Viennese ticket agency blog linked in the comments](https://www.concertvienna.com/blog/vienna-opera/how-to-attend-the-opera/):

> The overall rule is to look presentable and avoid showing up in travel attire. A sport coat and a pair of slacks should be just fine for any performance. A nice blouse with slacks or a semi-formal dress would also be a good choice for the ladies.
>
> Still, dressing up can be half the fun of going to the opera! So if possible, feel free to wear that stunning dress or suit you rarely have the chance to show off.

Comment: I decided to wear nice slacks, a tie, and a sport coat. I was a little overdressed for the standing room section but I fit right in with the crowd in the lobby and concession stand. I am glad I followed your advice and Weather Vane's advice. As an added bonus, twice on the way to the opera, people asked me for directions in German. They were genuinely surprised when I answered in English. For the first time ever, I blended in with the local crowd.